# Falha ao mostrar conteúdo de Longblob em site

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

Pessoal estou fazendo um site para um tcc do ensino médio e bom fiz em php um while que puxaria dados de uma tabela incluindo foto(armazenada como longblob), e bom na hora de executar esse código na pagina a imagem em vez de aparecer, aparece ela codificada, estou tentando resolver isso com urgencia mas não encontrei em nada como devo fazer pra mostrar uma longblob como imagem(banco do phpmyadmin). Se removo a imagem e bota um quadrado por exemplo, ele puxa os outros dados normalmente.

```
<?php
      $tipo =$_GET["tipo"];
      $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","db_tcc") or die ("Não foi possível se conectar com o servidor.");





        switch($tipo){
            case "0":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM tb_locaissp ORDER BY id ASC";
                    break;

            case "1": case "2": case "3":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM tb_locaissp WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY id ASC";
                    break;
    }


          $carregar_guias = mysqli_query($conexao, $varsql);

      while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($carregar_guias))
      {
        $id = $linha["ID"];
        $img = $linha["FOTO"];
        $nome = $linha["NOME"];
        $desc = $linha["DESCRICAO"];




        echo "<div class='loc'>
        <table class='tablel'>
        <tr><td class='nome'>$nome</td>  <td><img class='contador' src='like' '> </td></tr>
        <tr><td class='imglo'><img src='$img'></td></tr>
        <tr><td class='desc'>$desc</td></tr>
        </table></div>";
        echo "<br><br>";

      }
    ?>
```

Comment: a minha não aparece em binario e sim em vários caracteres diferentes. se eu tentar a solução para o de cima aonde colocaria a variavel de php?

Comment: Me parece ser a mesma solução, você já testou?

Comment: testei junto com o codigo GD que encontrei aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106470/php-convert-a-blob-into-an-image-file e estranhamente a imagem aparece mas embaixo dela fica os mesmo caracteres ocupando muito mas muito espaço.

Comment: ob_start(); 
imagejpeg($img, null, 80);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($data)  . '" />';